# Stuck at building Keycloak's example inside a docker container with JDK and Maven

Tags: java, docker, maven, keycloak

I'm not a Java developer. However, there is this Keycloak plugin in my company that provides phone + OTP login.

It's not built. I want to just build it and use the `.jar` file in our Keycloak. So I decided to build the example provided by the [Keycloak](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/tree/main/examples/providers/authenticator) team.

I created a `Dockerfile` to contain everything related to Java build, including JDK + Maven and Keycloak's source code:

```
FROM amd64/debian:bookworm-slim

RUN apt update -qq > /dev/null \
    && apt upgrade -qq > /dev/null \
    && apt install openjdk-17-jdk -qq -y > /dev/null \
    && apt install openjdk-17-jre -qq -y > /dev/null \
    && java -version \
    && echo 'export JAVA_HOME=$(dirname $(dirname $(readlink -f $(which java))))' >> /etc/bash.bashrc \
    && echo 'export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin' >> /etc/bash.bashrc \
    && mkdir -p /Temp > /dev/null \
    && chmod 777 --preserve-root /Temp > /dev/null \
    && echo 'public class HelloWorld { public static void main(String[] args) { System.out.println("Hello World from Java!"); } }' > /Temp/Hello.java \
    && java /Temp/Hello.java \
    && apt install wget -y > /dev/null \
    && wget https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/releases/download/23.0.3/keycloak-23.0.3.zip --quiet -O /Temp/keycloak.zip > /dev/null \
    && apt install unzip -y > /dev/null \
    && cd /Temp \
    && unzip keycloak.zip -d /Keycloak > /dev/null \
    && rm -rf keycloak.zip \
    && cd /Keycloak > /dev/null \
    && mv keycloak-23.0.3/** . > /dev/null \
    && rm -rf keycloak-23.0.3 > /dev/null \
    && ls -lah \
    && wget https://dlcdn.apache.org/maven/maven-3/3.9.5/binaries/apache-maven-3.9.5-bin.zip --quiet -O /Temp/maven.zip > /dev/null \
    && cd /Temp \
    && unzip maven.zip -d /usr/share > /dev/null \
    && rm -rf maven.zip \
    && ln -s /usr/share/apache-maven-3.9.5/bin/mvn /usr/bin/mvn \
    && echo 'M2_HOME=/usr/share/apache-maven-3.9.5' >> /etc/bash.bashrc

WORKDIR /Keycloak
```

It works fine.

Then I built it using `docker build -t java-keycloak .` and created a `docker-compose.yml` to run a container:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  accounts:
    image: java-keycloak
    working_dir: /Keycloak
    environment:
      - KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL=https://dev.accounts.local/
      - PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true
      - KC_HOSTNAME=dev.accounts.local
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=adminuser
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=adminpass
      - KC_PROXY=edge
      - KC_HTTP_ENABLED=true
      - KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT=false
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    command: >
      bash -c
      "
      tail -f /dev/null
      "
    volumes:
      - /Temp/keycloak:/KeycloakSource
```

Please note that I cloned the Keycloak source code into my local machine at `/Temp/keycloak` and mapped it inside the container. But when I run it, and go into the container using `docker exec -it container_name bash` and `cd /KeycloakSource/examples/providers/authenticator` and run `mvn clean install wildfly:deploy` I get this error:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  25.384 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-12-26T15:09:13Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project authenticator-required-action-example: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.keycloak:authenticator-required-action-example:jar:999.0.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.keycloak:keycloak-core:jar:999.0.0-SNAPSHOT (absent), org.keycloak:keycloak-server-spi:jar:999.0.0-SNAPSHOT (absent), org.keycloak:keycloak-server-spi-private:jar:999.0.0-SNAPSHOT (absent), org.keycloak:keycloak-services:jar:999.0.0-SNAPSHOT (absent): Could not find artifact org.keycloak:keycloak-core:jar:999.0.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

I know this might be a stupid question. But I'm not a Java developer. Any help is highly appreciated. What should I do to build the example of Keycloak inside a docker?

Comment: The defined dependency `org.keycloak:keycloak-core:jar:999.0.0-SNAPSHOT` is simply wrong... that version does not exist... ?

Comment: @khmarbaise, but I have not coded anything myself. I just installed JDK + Maven and mapped the Keycloak source. Do you mean that Keycloak team made that mistake?

Comment: No. You have a pom file which does not contain the correct version ...but without the full project is hard even to make an educated guess.. ?

Comment: I might normally expect you to `RUN mvn package` or similar as part of your Dockerfile; you should not need a volume mount or a do-nothing container.   Can you build this same package with a normal non-container JDK?

Comment: @khmarbaise, as I mentioned, I only copied the Keycloak source code. So if that project is incomplete, I can report it to them.

Comment: @DavidMaze, AMAIK that changes nothing. Running `RUN mvn clean install wildfly:deploy` would still encounter the same error. Even if I run that command on my machine (non-container) or inside the `Dockerfile` nothing is changed. It still won't work.